# Combing multiple json loads in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, merge

I am new to python, am used to php, and I am trying to figure out how to combine the json.loads from multiple data sets into one.

This is what I have:

```
import json
var = json.loads('{"root": [{"item 1": "1","item 2": "2","List1": [1,2,3]}]}')
var2 = json.loads('{"root": [{"item 1": "1","item 2": "2","List2": [1,2,3]}]}')
import pprint

print 'var:'
pprint.pprint(var);
print 'var2:'
pprint.pprint(var2);

print 'deepcopy:' 
import copy;
var3 = var;
var3 = copy.deepcopy(var2);
pprint.pprint(var3);

print 'dict copy:'
pprint.pprint(dict(var.items() + var2.items()));
```

Results in:

var:
{u'root': [{u'List1': [1, 2, 3], u'item 1': u'1', u'item 2': u'2'}]}

var2:
{u'root': [{u'List2': [1, 2, 3], u'item 1': u'1', u'item 2': u'2'}]}

deepcopy:
{u'root': [{u'List2': [1, 2, 3], u'item 1': u'1', u'item 2': u'2'}]}

dict copy:
{u'root': [{u'List2': [1, 2, 3], u'item 1': u'1', u'item 2': u'2'}]}

I am looking for a result like (including both lists), but including the duplicate items would be helpful as well, as then I will be heading in the right direction:

{u'root': [{u'List1': [1, 2, 3], u'List2': [1, 2, 3], u'item 1': u'1', u'item 2': u'2'}]}

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression

Comment: Thanks, that's where I got the "dict copy" item that I tried, print result #4.  Unfortunately that doesn't do it, I believe its because the parsed JSON is a mixture of dictionaries and lists.

Comment: @brainovergrow that situation is a bit more complex than the one OP is in

Answer (score 1):

This should give you want you want:

```
var3 = var
var3['root'][0].update(var2['root'][0])
```

Although I'm not sure why the `value` at the key `'root'` is a list with a single `dict` element.
If this isn't necessary, it'd be a lot cleaner if the `value` was just the `dict` itself, then you can do:

```
var3 = var
var3['root'].update(var2['root'])
```

Comment: I'm loading in multiple JSON files and I need to combine them into one array.  That structure is a simplified example of how the JSON files load.  This works thanks, so if I wanted to make this work for all cases, I could just create a function to loop through every element of array 1 and update with array 2?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JSON question, but a Python dict() one, since the output of `json.loads()` is a dictionary. What you really want is a way to combine 2 dictionaries. To create the desired result, you can do this

```
var3['root'] = var1.update(var2['root'])
```

Cheers!